# Navigation based web site in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, c#-4.0, google-maps-api-3

I want to develop a navigation based application in asp.net. I want to show a route with multiple way-points between a source and destination node in Google maps and I don't know how to do it.

E.g: when the user submits the destination with some way-points the map should display the route from the source to destination with those way-points on website.

You want to get from point A to point D, and on the way there are points B and C. The solution is to draw a route from A to B, B to C, and finally C to D.

Please help me to solve my problem.

Comment: You may start here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/

Comment: I have added Google-Maps tags to your question, I have assumed you are using the latest API version. Can you confirm you are using API v3?

Answer (score 0):

The majority of Google Maps applications use javascript,php &mysql so there is more information using these.

If you must use asp.net [THIS](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/291499/Google-Maps-API-V3-for-ASP-NET) will give you a start,

Comment: Many many thanks @David sir. This is really awesome article what i exact want. Thanks to all who gave me quick response. :)